# How to add new record using Bindingsource

Tags: .net, winforms, ado.net

i'm using a BindingSource in a .NET winform application. 
I'm trying to add a new record to my gridview. 
I suppose i've to write:

```
myBindingSource.AddNew
```

Then editing the value of the record and finally, call

```
myBindingSource.EndEdit
```

But, my record wasn't saved.

Where i'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be performed AcceptChanges the dataset, with the bindings add just the line, and not the update.

myDataSet.AcceptCgahges();

Regards.

Comment: It is not said that the data source is a dataset, is @stighy?